# Difference between Maps.filterKeys and Maps.filterValues in Guava

Tags: java, maps, guava

Trying to understand why we have separate methods Maps.filterKeys and Maps.filterValues.

If you pass the same predicate to either methods, will the result be not the same - as the predicate determines what is filtered.

Comment: It's quite obvious from method names that they do different things.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a `Map<K, V>` where K and V are the same classes, you cannot pass the same predicate:

```
Maps.filterKeys(Map<K, V> unfiltered, Predicate<? super K> keyPredicate);
Maps.filterValues(Map<K, V> unfiltered, Predicate<? super V> valuePredicate);
```

As the names imply, `filterKeys` filters the keys, `filterValues` filters the values.

Comment: Thank you. Missed the predicate signature had K